# Receiving launch notification data other than from Main launcher activity

Tags: android, notifications

I'm writing a library for Push notifications on Android. I don't want users to override the root activity for adding OnNewIntent method to pass launched notification information to my library.

Any possible way to solve this?

In short - Any way to get notification data when user clicks in the notification bar if we don't have access to launcher activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work without overriding the root activity.

I set the pending intent as the new activity where I want to receive the notification data and in its onCreate method I saved the intent data and launched the main activity from there!